# Problemas para listar dados do firebase no android

Tags: android, listview, firebase

Bom dia !
Estou com dificuldades para listar dados de um certo nó no meu aplicativo... quando eu vou lista-lo conforme os códigos abaixo eu tenho o seguinte retorno de exception: "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.ramattecgmail.rafah.herdeirosapp.Models.Cardapio" como o erro nçao informa qual objeto exatamente ele não consegue converter eu não consegui solucionar o problema. Abaixo segue como está a estrutura no firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

lista_cardapio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/fundo_cardapio">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_refeicao_lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Refeição"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_ingredientes_lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="O que teremos?"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_refeicao_lista"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ActivityCardapio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ramattecgmail.rafah.herdeirosapp.Activitys.CardapioActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_cardapio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/linha_cardapio"
    android:dividerHeight="0.3dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Cardapio.java(models)

```
public class Cardapio {
//ATRIBUTOS
private String refeicao;
private String ingredientes;
private String data;

public Cardapio(){

}

public void salvarCardapio(){

    //Pegando o ano atual
    Date ano = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    String anoRetiro = format.format(ano);

    //pegando o ano atual para salvar no nó retiro
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReference();
    reference.child("RETIRO")
            .child(anoRetiro)
            .child("CARDAPIO")
            .child(getData())
            .child(getRefeicao())
            .setValue(this);

}

public String getRefeicao() {
    return refeicao;
}

public void setRefeicao(String refeicao) {
    this.refeicao = refeicao;
}

public String getIngredientes() {
    return ingredientes;
}

public void setIngredientes(String ingredientes) {
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

CardapioAdapter.java

```
public class CardapioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cardapio> {
private ArrayList<Cardapio> arrayList;
private Context context;

public CardapioAdapter(@NonNull Context c, @NonNull ArrayList<Cardapio> objects) {
    super(c, 0, objects);
    this.arrayList = objects;
    this.context = c;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    //Validando e criando a lista
    if (arrayList != null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Montando a view a partir do XML
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_cardapio, parent, false);

        //Recuperando os componentes para exibição
        TextView refeicao = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_refeicao_lista);
        TextView ingredientes = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ingredientes_lista);

        Cardapio cardapio = arrayList.get(position);
        refeicao.setText(cardapio.getRefeicao());
        ingredientes.setText(cardapio.getIngredientes());

    }
    return view;
}
}
```

e por ultimo mas não menos importante, a activity que deveria exibir a lista
CardapioActivity.java

```
public class CardapioActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ATRIBUTOS
ListView listView;

private ArrayList<Cardapio> arrayList;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private DatabaseReference reference;
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cardapio);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //INSTANCIANDO OS COMPONENTES
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_cardapio);
    adapter = new CardapioAdapter(CardapioActivity.this, arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Pegando o ano atual
    Date ano = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
    String anoRetiro = format.format(ano);

    reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReference()
            .child("RETIRO")
            .child(anoRetiro)
            .child("CARDAPIO")
            .child("24")
            .child("11")
            .child("Almoço");

    valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayList.clear();

            //Listando os eventos
            for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Cardapio cardapio = data.getValue(Cardapio.class);
                arrayList.add(cardapio);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
}

/******************************** METODOS ********************************/
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    reference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    reference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
}

}
```

No reference ele possui o ultimo child("Almoço") apenas para testes pois o que quero é listar todas as refeições para o dia que eu passar por parametro(neste caso o 24 e o 11 serão passados dinamicamente), e se vocês observarem poderão ver que na classe Cardapio Model aonde eu faço a gravação por meio de um dialogFragment eu instancio a data e o firebase sozinho separa o dia do mês em seus nós conforme imagem... Desde já agradeço !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente o problema estava relacionado com o fato de que quando eu salvava os dados eu não adicionava nenhum tipo de chave, apenas dados puros nos nós, então adicionei uma criptografia justamente no nó que eu precisava trazer os filhos conforme imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma o mesmo código apresentado acima da conta de trazer os dados do cardapio que eu precisava, respondi para exemplo, se alguém tiver problemas para listar os dados do firebase, talvez adicionar uma criptografia no nó filho seja o suficiente se você estiver listando eles com dataSnapsho.getchildren